# Combining 2 roundtrip tickets

Tags: international-travel, fare-basis

I am travelling from country A to country B. I want to spend about a month in country B and I would like to repeat this journey in 6 months or so.

Are there any rules against buying 2 roundtrip tickets like so:
1) A-B September, return flight B-A May
2) B-A October, return flight A-B June

Then flying to B using the first leg of ticket #1 in September and coming back to A using the first leg of ticket #2 in October. Similar process in May.

Comment: this is called "nested returns" and most people do them on different airlines just in case

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find figure out the right term to google, now I know :)

Comment: Note that these are technically not "nested" as in XYYX, but rather "interleaved" as in XYXY.

Answer (score 8):

Nested returns are totally fine and quite common for say, Kiwis who have gone to live in London - 1 way over there, then returns from London to NZ, repeat for x years, then a 1 way back to NZ even.

I've also had LON-EZE return, and inbetween, went EZE to CHC and back, then back to London later.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys for some interesting reading.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure because I remember there was something that airlines definitely did not like back in the day. I can't find what it was now but it was something about combining multiple trips

Comment: @NoobTraveller they don't like you buying a return and then only using half of it, or trying to take the second leg of an itinerary, but as long as you take all legs of an itinerary, I've not had problems.

Comment: @MarkMayo: They don't like that you're paying them more money than you would be if you just bought a ticket for the one single leg?

Comment: @Sean on some routes, a return leg is actually *cheaper* than a one way, so then they really don't like it ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo: Yes, but the round-trip still costs more than the one-way (although _each individual leg_ costs less), so you're still paying them more money overall (since you have to buy the whole round-trip ticket even if you're only planning on actually flying one leg of it).

Comment: @Sean, nope, not always.  Eg from A to B costs $5, but A to B return costs $4.  Was with a friend when he bought a ticket like this from Bolivia to NZ, and often comes up in the US. Articles exist on this, eg https://traveltips.usatoday.com/one-way-ticket-cost-round-trip-ticket-109573.html

Comment: @MarkMayo: What?  That makes no sense - why would they make it so easy to effectively get a one-way leg for a much cheaper price than the one officially on offer?

Comment: As per the article @Sean, one-way tickets are inconvenient for them.  It explains how they try to recoup some of the inconvenience by making 1 way tickets more expensive

Comment: @Sean a case I personally experienced: one-way HEL–TXL was €500, the return trip HEL–TXL–HEL around €100. Needless to say which I took. (Same airline, same flight ftr.)